# Scipy - Ks2samps statistic location

Tags: python, scipy

I follow this official [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html#scipy.stats.ks_2samp) to conduct the two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. I would like to ask how to get the `statistic_location` (i.e., the location of maximum difference between the two CDFs). In the documentation, it specifies that the `ks_2samp` function can return the `statistic_location` but in fact it only returns the `statistic` and `pvalue`.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
n1 = np.random.normal(0,1,20)
n2 = np.random.normal(1,1,20)
stats.ks_2samp(n1,n2)
```

The result is:

```
KstestResult(statistic=0.55, pvalue=0.00396729438660086)
```

Comment: Which version of scipy/python are you using? Running your code I get the expected output with location and sign. The two were added in version 1.10 
 see: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/17062

Comment: Thank you @nlivingstone!! I use Python `3.9.3` but Scipy is `1.9.3` when I run `pip show scipy`. I will ask the IT to upgrade the package for me. Please make the answer and I will mark it done for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify SciPy version is >= v1.10. `location_statistics` and `statistic_sign` were added to the result of `ks_2samp()` in version 1.10. Source: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/17062